# Nullifidan, heresiarch, latitudinarian-- Is there some database where I can find other obscure words describing "types" of people?

Tags: vocabulary, loanwords, obscure-terms

I only come across these really obscure words while reading. I really love the weight they carry. Do you know of any place where I can find more words of the same family? If not, do you know any other words like this? Please don't say any words for specific phobias. I find those incredibly uninteresting :I

Thanks friends

Comment: Try https://osf.io/eu9hc/  But be prepared to find more words than you really want to see.

Comment: Have you tried a thesaurus based on semantic categories, such as Roget's? Such a thing allows you to browse words in different categories which may include "types of people". Other than that, there are lots of websites with selections of interesting words (most of the online dictionaries do "word of the day" type features); which you may be able to search through.